# to know what size image I need for the frame

Tags: after-effects

After a lot of research, i can't find how to do something stupid : I have a video template with photo frames in it. I would like to know what size image I need for the frame.
Problem, I can find the size of the composition (easy) but not the size of a layer ...
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Every asset in a project can be seen listed in the Project panel.

When you click on each asset, a preview should appear at the top of the panel, which shows you the dimensions of the asset, and the pixel aspect ratio - e.g. 1920x1080 (1.00) as shown below:

[image: grab2]

Comment: it works thanks !